# Android, how to send POST request

Tags: android, post, http-post

I can't send post request to the server from my Android app.
I have found some examples about how to send **POST** but I have some error with my code and here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private WebView wv; //Internet
private EditText email1; //Edit's
private EditText email2; //Edit's
private Button btn_get_access; //Get Access
private String post_url = "http://rasnacis.lv/vova.php";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    email1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_email_1);
    email2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_email_2);
    btn_get_access = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_access);

    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);

    //BUTTON
    OnClickListener ocl_btn_get_access = new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            String givenEmail1 = email1.getEditableText().toString();
            String givenEmail2 = email2.getEditableText().toString();

            //SENDING POST
            if (givenEmail1.length() > 0 && givenEmail2.length() > 0)
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(post_url);

                try
                {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email1", "email2"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email1", "slgjlskjgsg"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email2", "xkjfhgkdjfhgkdjfg"));

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All fields are required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //sending GET
            //wv.loadUrl("http://rasnacis.lv/vova.php?email1=" + email1.getText() + "&email2=" + email2.getText());
        }
    };
    btn_get_access.setOnClickListener(ocl_btn_get_access);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

so can somebody help me with it? i am just started Android development and don't know many tricks or something difficult...

Comment: Have you checked <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the **doPostRequest()** method to use in your application,

that is useful for you and *perfectly working* in my code...

```
private void doPostRequest(){

    String urlString = "http://rasnacis.lv/vova.php";
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("email1_tag", new StringBody("email1_put_here"));
        reqEntity.addPart("email2_tag", new StringBody("email2_put)here"));
        reqEntity.addPart("email3_tag", new StringBody("email3_put_here"));
        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        resEntity = response.getEntity();
        final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    try {
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

If you Implement this code you **required** two **library** files:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.0.1/httpmime-4.0.1.jar

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j/0.6/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar

Comment: can you please tell me, what i need to include into project for MultipartEntity, StringBody and resEntity, because now i have an error on this..

Comment: @vladimir Actualy you don't need `MultipartEntity` always. Use `HttpEntity` it will do for you

Comment: @pKs
ok, but what about resEntity... what type or object is it?

Comment: emmm, i have some question about this code, because in my case programm hangs on string MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
and nothing happens next..

Comment: you have to required library file which is download from following link... 1st-->
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.0.1/httpmime-4.0.1.jar
 and 2nd-->
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j/0.6/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar

Comment: _+1_ HttpPost is deprecated since android api level 21

Answer (score 13):

i have use this technique to knock server using post method:

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {
          query = "name="+username+"&pass="+passwaord;

          URL url = new URL("https:www.example.com/login.php");
          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
          //Set to POST
          connection.setDoOutput(true);
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
          Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
          writer.write(query);
          writer.flush();
          writer.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           Log.e(Tag, e.toString());
       }
    }
}).start();
```

i hope it will help. be sure that, cookie is need or not to post for your purpose. if not then u can ignore `connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);` line.

`query` can be created by `BasicNameValuePair`, but the proccess i have used is lot more easier to me.

make sure u have set the permission in your manifest for internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer, making the POST on a runnable thread will prevent getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Thanks!

Comment: Also the Apache libraries have been removed in Android Marshmallow so this is now the only viable option.

Comment: where is the result?

Comment: how to get response of the post request?

Comment: @AsadullahAli: I have not coded on android for a very long time. but, i think you can get the response from `connection.getInputStream()`.